# How to know which documents belong to collections

Tags: marklogic

I have a list of files contain only the documentID.  How do I know the documentID belongs to which collections in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of collections that a document belongs to with [`xdmp:document-get-collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-collections)

If you want to know which documents belong to a given collection(s), then you can use [`cts:collection-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:collection-query) with `cts:search()` or `cts:uris()`